# Проблемы с Rigidbody, Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Rigidbody ведёт себя неадекватно при трении об коллайдер. Несколько секунд двигаемся, прикасаясь к коллайдеру, потом то, что мы двигаем, дёргает и разворачивает, будто отталкивая слишком сильно и в противоположном направлении.

Rigidbody Continious Dynamic, Interpolate - Interpolate. На неподвижном коллайдере нет Rigidoby.

Код движения Rigidbody крайне прост

```
body.AddForce(transform.forward * forwardForce);
body.AddTorque(0, rb.velocity.magnitude * rotate, 0, ForceMode.Acceleration);
```

Неподвижный коллайдер меш, подвижный, который с Rigidbody - капсула.

Comment: А масса тела какая?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ
Да вроде всё адекватно - у предмета, который мы двигаем, масса 1000.
У неподвижного - массы нет.

Comment: Значения сил при массе 1000 у вас какие?

Comment: И какого эффекта вы пытаетесь достичь?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ
Для максимальной скорости по 1 оси, примерно 8000.
Велосити при этом равна 10

Comment: @StrangerintheQ
Плавного трения с небольшим замедлением скорости, об стены. Стандартное поведение при движении вдоль стены

Comment: И как вы решили что все нормально? Если все это в системе си например?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  
Не вычислял вручную физику данного взаимодействия, но, понимаю, 7 класс. Вы уже видите что что то неправильно?

Comment: Пробуйте соотношения близкие к 1, будет более предсказуемый результат

Comment: Еще есть у коллайдеров трение и упругость

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83833/discussion-between-dmitrii-and-stranger-in-the-q).